# Set SkipGeographyChecks to true

Tags: geometry, entity-framework-core, polygon

Hi I get this exception when saving multiple polygons. How can I set **SkipGeographyChecks** to true ?

Exception:

> When writing a SQL Server geography value, the shell of a polygon must be oriented counter-clockwise. To write polygons without a shell, set SkipGeographyChecks

Code sample :

```
var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
var poly = new Polygon[] {
new Polygon(new LinearRing(new Coordinate[]
{
        new Coordinate(19.2385498607974, -51.50390625,0),
        new Coordinate(24.1367281697474, -37.6171875,0),
        new Coordinate(13.8487471475372, -18.10546875,0),
        new Coordinate(19.2385498607974, -51.50390625,0),
                    })),
new Polygon(new LinearRing(new Coordinate[]
{
        new Coordinate(-10.0445849842118, -53.0859375,0),
        new Coordinate(4.13824308398371, -58.7109375,0),
        new Coordinate(2.20770545570541, -68.73046875,0),
        new Coordinate(-8.83079518432893, -79.1015625,0),
        new Coordinate(-17.3820949478775, -81.2109375,0),
        new Coordinate(-21.0332372344673, -51.328125,0),
        new Coordinate(-10.0445849842118, -53.0859375,0),
})) 
};

var currentLocation = geometryFactory.CreateMultiPolygon(poly) as MultiPolygon;
dbset.Polygons = currentLocation;
_context.Add(dbset);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, SkipGeographyChecks was removed as a property before the reference to it was removed from this error - [Github issue for removing the reference to this property](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes/commit/5ef7c4033be364f35473399c1ff5445fd47acd98).

I also found that this error may arise if the points of your polygon are ordered in the wrong direction. The convention is that the direction of the points what the "inside" of the polygon is - ie: if points for a polygon are counterclockwise, the area of that polygon is inside the boundary, but if the points are clockwise then the area is the entire world *except* for inside that boundary (because the points are essentially counterclockwise around everything outside of the boundary). You can determine if this is your issue by checking the `IPolygon.Shell.IsCCW` property. If this is your issue, you can solve it by using the `IPolygon.Shell.Reverse()` method. See [this GIS StackExchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247429/fixing-orientation-in-net-topology-suite) (where I found this information) for some actual code you can use.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will save someone some time.

I also needed to solve the error (**polygon must be oriented counter-clockwise**) OP quoted in question.
I was looking for a clean way to solve the problem without having to **reverse geometries everywhere**.

After reading through a couple of issues I gathered the following:

- Configure `NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices` to simplify working with geometries

  - [image]
- The `GeometryFactoryEx` class was created to handle orientation

  - [image]
- Extend `NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices` to use `GeometryFactoryEx` throughout application (see [this comment](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes/issues/13#issuecomment-707135732) )

### Here is what I ended up needing

#### A class that extends `NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices`

I just added the constructor I required.

```cs
    public class NtsGeometryServicesEx : NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices
    {
        public NtsGeometryServicesEx() { }

        public NtsGeometryServicesEx(PrecisionModel precisionModel, int srid)
            : base(precisionModel, srid)
        {
        }
        

        protected override GeometryFactory CreateGeometryFactoryCore(
            PrecisionModel precisionModel,
            int srid,
            CoordinateSequenceFactory coordinateSequenceFactory)
        {
            return new GeometryFactoryEx(precisionModel, srid, coordinateSequenceFactory);
        }
    }
```

#### Assigning my required configuration to default `NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices` instance on application startup

```cs
  // set default NTS Geometry Services
  NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices.Instance
    = new Infrastructure.Spatial.NtsGeometryServicesEx(
      PrecisionModel.Floating.Value, GeometryExtensions.Wgs84Srid);
```

And voila! - solved the shell orientation errors.

Comment: I've implemented this exactly as you have and am running `NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid)` to create my polygons, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @NickyLarson it's quite difficult to know what your complete configuration looks like without more info, but taking a stab in the dark, did you replace default `NtsGeometryServices.Instance` with your extended version? If yes, did you replace the default instance early enough before trying to use `NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory`? E.g. I replace default instance in **Program.cs**